# Can I use an executable file in Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to use a package (pershombox) in Colab, dependent on third party software tools in executable form that I need to upload myself.

Is this possible, and if so which operating system's version do I need to upload?

Comment: If possible, could you please upload what you have tried so far? People will understand the problem faster if you provide the sources.

Comment: Do you want me to edit in the error report I get? I am asking because I cannot yet manage to paste it as text, but I can post it as a picture. Suffice to say I uploaded into my google drive the executable file that does work in my computer and it raises a PermissionError so it's not being executed.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it. Google Colaboratory uses a version of Ubuntu for its VMs, and you can run shell commands by placing a `!` at the start of the line. As an example, I've just run `cat /etc/os-release` to display the OS info.

[image: Screenshot of Google Colaboratory]

So if you have a `.deb` file for the software you need, you can do this:

```
!chmod +x path_to_your_file.deb
!sudo dpkg -i path_to_your_file.deb
```

or if you instead have a *link* to the `.deb` file (usually faster, in my experience):

```
!wget https://link.to.file/file.deb
!chmod +x file.deb
!sudo dpkg -i file.deb
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I should probably add that one may also need to change permissions on the file in question via chmod, specifically to add execute (+x).

Comment: @IoannisGiannakaras Thanks for mentioning that! I'll add it to my answer.